# Нужна ли запятая в скобках? 3

Tags: пунктуация

Если затрагивать вопрос цены на оборудование в нашем сегменте, то цена выросла у многих производителей(,) и у российских в том числе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если затрагивать вопрос цены на оборудование в нашем сегменте, то цена выросла у многих производителей, и у российских в том числе.

Из справочника по пунктуации: союз В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ не отделяется от стоящих перед ним союзов А, И, образуя с ними единую конструкцию:

На другой день князь Андрей поехал с визитами в некоторые дома, где он еще не был, и в том числе к Ростовым, с которыми он возобновил знакомство на последнем бале.

Никогда Федор Никитич, ценивший все изящное, а в том числе и геометрию, не предполагал, что это прекрасное математическое понятие, обозначающее часть площади криволинейной фигуры, будет так опошлено.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Sibylla отвечала не на тот вопрос, ну да ладно... Запятая нужна, она отделяет присоединительную конструкцию.